# Auto calculate and return a field based on request in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a list of books with pincode of the location it was added from. I am getting a post request with pincode of user who wants to get such list. The list needs to be sorted according to the distance from the user.

Although I have a function to calculate the distance, I want to return a dynamic field named 'distance' in response.

My Book models is like:-

```
class Book(TimestampedModel):
user = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    null=True
)
name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
desc = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=False)
price = models.IntegerField(null=True)
pincode = models.IntegerField(null=False)
```

My serializer is like:-

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""Serializer for book object"""

class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = ('id', 'user', 'name', 'desc', 'is_active', 'sold_to', 'is_sold',
              'age', 'price', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'pincode')
```

and my view looks like:-

```
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
serializer_class = serializers.BookSerializer
queryset = Book.objects.all()

query_params = self.request.query_params

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    
    if('pincode' in query_params):
        pincode = query_params['pincode']
        try:
            for counter, instance in enumerate(queryset):
                instance.distance = dist.query_postal_code(
                    pincode, instance.pincode)
            queryset = sorted(queryset, key=attrgetter('distance'))
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)

    return queryset
```

As you can see, I am able to calculate the distance in the view, I am not sure how to send this in response.

Please help me I will definitely help you some day :P

Comment: Can you share how you calculating the distance please?

Comment: I am using a library named 'pgeocode' and using a function - dist.query_postal_code(pincode, instance.pincode) in my view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code in serializer:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    distance = serializers. SerializerMethodField()

    @property
    def get_query_pincode(self):
        return self.context['request'].query_params.get('pincode', None)

    def get_distance(self, obj):
        if self.get_query_pincode:
            # Your distance calcualting code here
            return distance
        return None
```

Next in the `Meta` class:

```
class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = ('id', 'user', 'name', 'desc', 'is_active', 'sold_to', 'is_sold',
              'age', 'price', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'pincode', 'distance')
```

You will need to add the new field in `fields` attribute and since its not an actual model field, `SerializerMethodField` is read only field.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But how would I pass value of pincode from my view to model?

And what is custom model method? Till now I was trying @property to compute fields

Comment: @ShubhamGupta Just missed that, made the necessary edits. Plz check now if it works.

Comment: Not sure if this works. See I have two pin codes, one already in my book model and other from the user making request. In my serializer I can access the book pincode, but not the user's pincode. Still need clarity. Surely some code change is also needed in views to pass in the user's pincode.

Comment: Right in views override the `list` function of `ModelViewSet` and Use your custom searilizer directly for each object in `queryset` like, `BookSerializer(obj, pincode)`

Comment: tried it and getting - TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'pincode'

Not able to follow you. If you can please show the updated view method in your answer to just make it complete and make me follow that would be great. This might be intuitive for you but I am unable to get my head around this.

Comment: Please try the above changes, keep the view as it is just remove the distance calculation code from views.

Comment: Thanks Reshab. Have got the desired results with minor tweaks

Comment: Good to know subham

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have managed to do return a custom field. Following changes were made to my view and serializer.

1. Passing user's pincode (request's **contextual** info) to my serializer through context in serializer

   ```
    def list(self, request):
            queryset = self.get_queryset()

            serializer = serializers.BookDetailSerializer(
                queryset, context={'query_params': request.query_params}, many=True)

            return Response(serializer.data)
   ```
2. Accessed Pincode through the passed context in distance function defined in serialzer:-

   pincode = self.context['query_params']['pincode']

PS - Thanks Reshab Das for giving some directions